# Excel VBA Class Module: Is it possible to create a "personalized" Range Object?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a class module in Excel VBA, called, say, myRange, which behave exactly like an Excel.Range object, but in which we can add new methods and properties?

For example

```
dim rg1 as Excel.Range, rg2 as myRange
set rg1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)
set rg2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(2,1)
```

With both objects, we could use all methods and properties of the Range object, using VBE Intellisense.

But, with rg2, we would have additional melhods and properties, created inside the myRange class module, and those new methods and properties, as well, could be seen in the Intellisense VBE drop-down list.

Examples of new properties:

```
TotWords = rg2.TotalOfWordsInMyCells
if Color = 2 then rg2.PaintMeYellow
```

Does Excel VBA have such capabilities?

Comment: You can't really "extend" Range - you can create a "wrapper" class which hold an internal reference to a range, but if you wanted all existing Range methods exposed via that class you'd need to replicate them in your class.  Or have your class expose the contained range via its own `Range` property, so you could use that for existing methods.  i.e. you can use `rg2.PaintMeYellow` (custom method) and `rg2.Range.ClearContents` for example.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for the quick reply. Sounds good to me, I mean, that is exactly what I wanted class modules could afford before diving into studying them. If you add your comment to an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really "extend" `Range` - you can create a "wrapper" class which holds an internal reference to a range, but if you wanted all existing Range methods exposed via that class you'd need to replicate them in your class. Or have your class expose the contained range via its own Range property, so you could use that for existing methods. i.e. you can use `rg2.PaintMeYellow` (custom method) and `rg2.Range.ClearContents` (existing `Range` method).

Basic example:

Class myRange:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private m_rng As Range

Sub Init(rng As Range)
    Set m_rng = rng
End Sub

Public Sub PaintMeYellow()
    Me.Range.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub

Property Get Range() As Range
    Set Range = m_rng
End Property
```

Example usage:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim rng As New myRange
    
    rng.Init ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B10") 'set the range reference
    
    rng.PaintMeYellow          'call a custom method
    
    rng.Range.ClearContents    'call built-in method on contained range
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, many thanks! I just loved it. I tested here and even the Intellisense worked as desired. I like the way the Intellisense shows only the created methods and properties, and, if the Range property is chosen, it shows the built-in's. Now I can [1] have a more organized code (into class module), [2] use intellisense a lot and [3] have a better code (I mean, a line of code where I read "rng.PaintMeYellow", and the like, seems more "natural" to read).